# Simple Subclassing

Tags: c++, oop

I have been recently introduced with the concept of object-oriented programming in C++ and I need help in deriving a class. I believe the solution for this problem is trivial, and it's just that I'm not familiar with some class deriving basics.

So I have this:

```
struct Circle : Shape
{
    /* ... */
}
```

... and it works good. I tried to subclass Circle like this:

```
struct Smiley : Circle
{
    using Circle::Circle; // use Circle's constructors?
    /* ... */
}
```

When I try to initialize Smiley with some arguments in main(), I get this type error:

```
no instance of constructor "Graph_lib::Smiley::Smiley" matches the argument list
```

The main() looks like this:
    `Smiley happy{ Point{ 300, 200 }, 100 };`

When I replace class name from Smiley to Circle, everything works just fine.

`Circle happy{ Point{ 300, 200 }, 100 }; // this is ok and working`

This is Circle's declaration:

```
struct Circle : Shape {
    Circle(Point p, int rr);    // center and radius

    void draw_lines() const;

    Point center() const ; 
    int radius() const { return r; }
    void set_radius(int rr) { r=rr; }
private:
    int r;
};
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code in `main()`?

Comment: `Smiley happy{ Point{ 300, 200 }, 100 };` , when I replace Smiley with Circle it works fine.

Comment: Why use `struct` and not `class`?

Comment: Give us a behavior reproducing minimal example.

Comment: The language feature you appear to be using is [*Constructor Inheritance*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), and it at-first appears your setup could be correct, but without knowing the actual constructors for `Circle` and how you're constructing your `Smiley` it is impossible to tell. Also, including your toolchain info would be a decent addition to your question while adding accurate source that reflects your issue. [See example](http://ideone.com/SEBpst).

Comment: I didn't think It was relevant. Circle has a valid public constructor that works fine when used separately.

Comment: If your code looks like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bfca4e260f0984b) then it's fine. This sounds like the code you describe, but unless you post it we can't tell.

Comment: Posting a complete program which is as small as possible while still reproducing whatever error you're asking about is a good practice when asking for help.

Comment: Your code is correct, only one thing, center and radius are private. You say it's fine, but for some reason I get this error.

Comment: Will post more code.

Comment: @user3650284 Are you saying you get an error with the exact code I posted? What compiler are you using?

Comment: __Unable to reproduce:__ http://ideone.com/vXcCx7 Please create a code sample that I can run on ideone.com that throws the error you are concerned with.

Comment: I didn't try your code, but it is the SAME as mine, except that Shape base class is defined.

Comment: Whatever problem you're encountering, it is in code you're not showing us or it's due to something else you haven't told us, such as the compiler version you're using.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community I downloaded a few months ago. But I do get "The project is out of date" warning before compiling. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler was the problem. I downloaded November 2013 compiler and now everything works fine. Thanks @bames53

Answer (score -1):

First there is a slight difference between struct and classes. It mainly has to deal with public/private, but there is a difference. Your issue is coming from the "using Circle::Circle". Without a more detailed code sample I can't really debug more. However, the first place to start would be to look at the parameters of the circle constructor. If you are trying to pass a different kind if initialization parameter (i.e char instead of int) to Smiley it won't work.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. I already said a few times: I used the same arguments in main() for Smiley and Circle. Circle variable works fine, while Smiley gives this "invalid args" error, but Smiley should inherit the Circle's constructor which is valid.